# Comando For não funcionando com uso do Findstr

Tags: cmd, prompt, bat, ms-dos

Estou tentando executar o comando `for` no prompt de comando para deletar todos os meus arquivos que possuam o texto `"< cd_comiss>P< /cd_comiss>"`, atribuindo eles a uma variável `%%e`, porém ele me retorna que:

> *%e foi inesperado neste momento*

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

**Obs.:** Estou navegando até a pasta que desejo para depois rodar o comando:

```
for /f %%e in ('findstr "<cd_comiss>P</cd_comiss>" *.*') do del %%e
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para a forma que está querendo executar basta alterar a forma que está utilizando a variável, ao invés de utilizar `%%e` utilize `%e`:

```
for /f %e in ('findstr "<cd_comiss>P</cd_comiss>" *.*') do del %e
```

---

Somente para esclarecer, a utilização de variável é diferente quando se deseja executar diretamente pelo Prompt ou executar um arquivo de lote.

Quando executar diretamente pelo prompt utilize: `%e` 
Quanto for por arquivo de lote, utilize: `%%e`

Conforme orienta a documentação, em tradução livre:

> {% Variável | %% variável}: Obrigatório. Representa um parâmetro
>   substituível. Use a variável % para executar a partir do prompt de
>   comando. Use a variável %% para executar o comando for dentro de um
>   arquivo em lotes. As variáveis diferenciam maiúsculas de minúsculas e
>   devem ser representadas com um valor alfa, como% A,% B ou% C.

Veja a documentação [aqui](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

### - Código *[**`bat`**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83aiz3xdWNA) [**`Suicida`**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamikaze)*: Evite isso!!

---

no bat:

> - **`for /f %%e in ('findstr "<cd_comiss>P</cd_comiss>" *.*')do del %%e`**

no prompt:

> - **`for /f %e in ('findstr "<cd_comiss>P</cd_comiss>" *.*')do del %e`**

---

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Apaga todos os arquivos com a **string** (e sem ela), até o próprio **Bat**, não usou filtros, qualquer um dos caráteres tá valendo, e ainda, está permitindo a ação em todos os arquivos **"`*.*`"**...

---

- **Obs.:** Lógico que só apagaria se o código funcionasse, mas felizmente não funciona, visto que, o comando **`findstr`** e o **`for`**, precisam de caracteres de **escape** nos: **[\, /, ^, <, >,< |, &, etc,...](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr-escapes.html)**. - Aplica-se também a virgula **`","`**

---

> ```
> Apaga todos os arquivos com a string, menos o próprio Bat, use filtro:
>    |findstr /vilc:"%~0"
> Ou, Apaga todos os arquivos com a string, menos o próprio Bat, use filtro:
>    |findstr /vilc:".cmd"
> ```

---

Já com o uso de escape, daí fica mais **controlado/filtrado** esse tipo de processamento, e até vai funcionar, mas termina em apagar/listar até um **Arquivo.gif**, arquivo que nem tem a **string** (completa) procurada no seu conteúdo, mas vai ser apagado porque algum caractere da string vai bater!
Nesse comando/código, o **`findstr`** esta sendo usado no tratamento de todos os arquivos (**`*.*`**), e como o **`findstr`** tende a tratar tudo como **`Regex`** (salvo com uso de **`/L`**, **`/c:`**, **`\`**, **`I`**, etc..), assim, qualquer caractere do arquivo que bater acaba valendo...:

---

> - Procure não usar **sem filtros** nos **comandos**: ***`del, deltree, rmdir, move, ren, rename, etc...`***

---

- Use **sempre** com um **filtro** de forma mais **segura/precisa**, ***passe por um*** ***`echo`*** ***antes***:
- **Implemente uma filtragem** para pegar uma **extensão especifica:**  - Exemplo: **`"*.xml"`**

---

```
for /f %%e in ('findstr "^<cd_comiss^>P^<\/cd_comiss^>" *.xml^|findstr /vilc:"*\.cmd"')do echo/del %%e
```

---

> Usando um **`bat`** para **encontrar e deletar** arquivos **.xml e só as que estão contendo a string**:
>    *(**"`<cd_comiss>P</cd_comiss>"`**)*:

- **Obs.:** A string está apenas nos arquivos .xml pares: **002, 004, 006, 008, 010**!

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

```
@echo off && setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion & echo/

echo/ & title <nul & title Q213311 & mode 100,10 & set "_str="\^<\ cd\_comiss\^>P\^<\ \/cd\_comiss\^>"" & echo/ 
for /f %%c in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul')do set "_cr=%%c" & for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (0) do rem"')do set "_bs=%%a"

for /f %%f in ('where /r . "*.*"^|findstr /vilc:"%~0"')do for /f ^tokens^=^*delims^=^  %%E in ('type %%f^|findstr /ilm !_str!')do (
     ping -n 2 -4 127.0 >nul & echo/ !_cr! & del /q /f "%%~f" >nul && <nul set /p"^=!_bs!!_cr! ^|Arquivo:^| "%%~f" ^| Apagado^!!"
    )
```